# Convert normal list to specific nested list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list in python that looks like that: `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]`. I would like to convert this list to a list of lists (nested list). The second level of lists should contain four elements maximal. Therefore, the new list should look like that:

```
[
  [a,b,c,d],
  [e,f,g,h],
  [i],
]
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this? I will have to do this several times so I would be pleased if anybody knows a way of doing this without using hundreds of indexes.

Comment: You need to use slices.  Try something like `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i][4:4]` and see what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange), and [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e',' f', 'g',' h', 'i']
>>> n = 4  # Size of sublists
>>> [lst[x:x+n] for x in xrange(0, len(lst), n)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i']]
>>>
```